# Add/remove active class to toggle

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

Ive created this little toggle, but I'm still figuring out how can I add a class 'active' to my < ul > when you click  to open the toggle, and remove the 'active' class once you close it.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0mpuh2f2/

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="accordion-media-types">
 <li>
  <a href="">Info</a>
    <div class="hidden-content">
      content
    </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('click','.accordion-media-types a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500);
});
```

thanks in advance any help.

Comment: `$('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500).toggleClass('active');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[YOUR UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0mpuh2f2/6/):**

```
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-media-types a', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('.accordion-media-types').toggleClass('active').find('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: Pleasure @user3507631

Answer (score 1):

You can use `siblings` to find the `hidden-content` div which is next to `a` tag, otherwise it will toggle all `hidden-content` div present in DOM and use `toggleClass()` toggle `active` class for div.

```
$(document).on('click','.accordion-media-types a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500);
    //toggle class to ul
    $(this).closest('.accordion-media-types').toggleClass('active');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0mpuh2f2/5/)**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it works! although is it possible to add the active class to the < ul > ? instead to the hidden content?

Comment: yes it is possible, see my updated answer. by using `closest()` you can get parent `ul` and then use `toggleClass()`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna add active class for your link use the code

```
                $(document).on('click','.accordion-media-types a', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    $('.hidden-content').slideToggle(500);
                });
```